# Git push commit cross branch, fetch commit from one branch to another

Tags: git

I have a github repo `origin` which has two branch, `master` and `new`. I have two work machines A and B. I first init this repo in B and local branch in B is tracking `master`. Then I created a branch and did some commit in A for `new`.

But, now I was trying to push my 'commit again' in B to `new`. What should I do? Or Where am I wrong?

I'm a newbie for git and I did read some tutorial for myself. Still have no idea how or why. Please help.

========== How this looks like ========================

```
-----------(master)--------------->(new)
              |                      |
              |                      |
          tracked by B         tracked by A
              |                      |
              B---->1.some commit      A----> 2.brach and some commit
                 -->3.some commit again
```

Comment: You say you created branch `new` after committing to `master`, so `new` should already contain everything that B has..

Comment: @Joost Yes, and I do some commit in B again.

Comment: Your question _implies_ it, but does not really mention it anywhere. Your drawing contradicts it. Try to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout new && git cherry-pick master && git push`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well what you want is to push your changes from A to B, in the same branch, that's correct?

git doesn't have a central repository, so you can push it directly from A to B.

If you've some kind of central repository you can just push to it, and then pull in your other local machine.

```
git push origin new
```

Assuming your central repository alias is origin.

You also can add your work machine B:

```
git remote add <new_name> <machine B uri>
```

**new_name** is just a name to identify your other local machine, so you can push to it as you would do to origin, just changing the name

```
git push <new_name> new
```

If there's any change on the meantime in the branch new in B you wouldn't be able to push directly, you'll need to pull the changes first.

If you want to keep the [history simpler](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/) you can rebase your changes first:

```
git pull --rebase <new_name> new
```

And then push your changes

```
git push <new_name> new
```

Let me know if it helps.